# Redux compose() typescript ownprops

Tags: typescript, redux

I have a complex composed component like:

```
export const NutrientEditorEnhanced = compose(
  withNutrientUnits,
  withNutrientByCode,
  withUpsertNutrient,
  withForm
)(NutrientEditor);
```

How can I define type of this HOC ownprops? Now typescript borrows props from the actual NutrientEditor, which is wrong. Maybe I could do it with recompose?

I tried `compose<IOwnProps>`, `compose<any,any,any,any,IOwnProps>` and it doesn't help

Thanks

P.S.

I need to use it like `<NutrientEditorEnhanced code={code} />` and no other props

Comment: what exactly is the problem your trying to solve ?

Comment: Hi! I'm trying to figure out how to make typescript aware of which exactly props the HOC  created with compose should receive when instantiating in jsx

Comment: it's better to use `compose` from `recompose`, this is what I found out long ago :-)